# How to pass client id and client secret to GoogleOauthConfig from os environment variable?

Tags: go, google-oauth

I am building a project in golang and I'd like to use environment variable for client id and client secret for google auth, but for some reason it is not working when using os.Getenv(). Google is saying missing "Missing required parameter: client_id" "Error 400: invalid_request". Which seems to me that it is not able to retrieve it from os.Getenv() and pass it over.

```
var (
    GoogleOauthConfig = &oauth2.Config{
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:8080/GoogleCallback",
        ClientID:     os.Getenv("GOOGLE_KEY"),
        ClientSecret: os.Getenv("GOOGLE_SECRET"),
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
    OauthStateString = "random"
)
```

Google auth works though without os.Getenv() and if I pass client id and client secret in directly as a string. Environment variable also works separately when I just put to main function fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_KEY")) and print it out to terminal.

```
var (
    GoogleOauthConfig = &oauth2.Config{
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:8080/GoogleCallback",
        ClientID:     "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        ClientSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        },
        Endpoint: google.Endpoint,
    }
    OauthStateString = "random"
)
```

What should I do, to make it work?

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable? If you just assign the return value from `os.Getenv` to a variable (`val := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_KEY")`), and print it, what do you see?

Comment: @larsks I read it in from .env file and set it with os.Setenv()
val := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_KEY") prints out the value of GOOGLE_KEY. Same if I just use fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_KEY")) and os.Getenv() works for github auth. Just doen't work with Google Oauth for some reason.